# Passing an id as a hidden parameter on a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The "architecture" of my application is as follows:
Users have Students.
Students have books and lessons.

As things stand, I am able to pass the student id as a hidden parameter through the book/new form. I'm trying to do the same for lessons. When I'm at students/2/lessons/new, I want to be able to pass that "2" when I create the book. I haven't gotten it to work, and I get an error for undefined method "id" when I try. I cut and pasted the same line of code that functions on my books controller to my lessons controller, but no success.

Lessons Controller:

```
class LessonsController < ApplicationController

def new
    @lesson = Lesson.new
end

def show

end

def create
    @lesson = Lesson.new(lesson_parameters)
    if @lesson.save
        redirect_to @lesson
    else
        redirect_to 'lessons#index'
    end
end

def index
     if params[:student_id]
  @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
  @lessons = @student.lessons

    else
      @lessons = Lesson.all
    end
end

private


def lesson_parameters
    params.require(:lesson).permit(:reading_notes, :writing_notes, :teaching_points)
end



 end
```

Students Controller

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController

def show
    @student = Student.find(params[:id]) rescue nil
    @books = Book.where(student_id: params[:id])
    @book = Book.new  


end

def create
    @student = Student.new(student_parameters)
    @student.user_id = current_user.id
    if @student.save
        redirect_to @student
    else
        redirect_to 'students#index'
    end
end


def index
    @students = Student.where("user_id = ?",current_user.id)
    @student = Student.new  
end

private

def student_parameters
    params.require(:student).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
end





end
```

Form Partial for New Lessons

```
<%= simple_form_for(@lesson, html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>


 <div class="form-inputs">          
  <%= f.input :student_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => {:value  => @student.id } %>
<%= f.input :reading_notes %>
<%= f.input :writing_notes %>
<%= f.input :teaching_points %>
</div>


<div class="form-actions">
   <%= f.button :submit %>
 </div>
```

Routes

```
  resources :books
    resources :users, only: [:new, :create, :show]
    resources :lessons 

 resources :students do
   resources :books
   resources :lessons
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `:student_id` in your permitted parameters.

It should be:

```
params.require(:lesson).permit(:student_id, :reading_notes, :writing_notes, :teaching_points)
```

Don't forget to permit your params. If your lesson now has the student_id defined everything should work properly.

Also you should try another way of simple-form using nested objects

```
<%= simple_form_for([@lesson, @student] ...
```

Or the other way around.

Comment: You're right. That's my mistake, I initially had student_id in there, but removed it while experimenting. When I copy and paste your line of code in, I still get  "undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass" on http://localhost:3000/students/2/lessons/new.

Comment: You should also do the following in your `new` action in the LessonsController: `@student = Student.find(params[:student_id])`